# Comparing two means from the same participants

Tags: t-test, mean

I have a question on comparing two means (from categories A and B). All the measurements were taken once from a single group (30 participants). The experiment applied 100 stimuli to each participant. When prompted, participants produced either A or B for each stimulus (that is, for a given stimulus, some participants produced A and some, B). All participants were exposed to the same stimuli. The duration of the productions of A and B were measured in milliseconds (ms). Thus, I have a table that looks like this:

[image]

This is the summary table showing the number of category A and B collected, the mean and the standard deviation for each category.

[image]

I would like to compare those two means and see whether they are significantly different and thus determine whether duration plays a role or not on how to tease categories A and B apart. My understanding is that I could use a t-test but I’m confused about which one would be the most appropriate for my case. The data come from a single group of people, but it is not paired since the measurements were taken once and also each person produced a different number of As and Bs. Should I use an independent t-test? (but my understanding is that it compares the averages of two samples that were selected independently of each other). Thanks.

Comment: If you want to use Duration to predict Category, you probably want to treat Category as the the dependent variable, and use something like logistic regression.  The observations should be treated on non-independent (paired) because there are multiple observations for the same person.

Comment: Thanks, but what I was hoping to find out is whether those two means are significantly different or not (namely, whether they indeed belong to two different distributions). I was wondering whether I could take one of the means as a point of reference and compare it to the other mean by applying a (one-tailed) One-sample t-test?

Comment: You can compare the means, but it doesn't make sense to use a one-sample t-test.  You want something akin to a paired *t* test, but since you have multiple observations per Participant, and want to account for the effect of both Stimuli and Category, you probably want to use a more complex model.